# Filter nested obejct

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

So I have this function that in theory should filter an array of movies by a given genre, but i get this error:

```
TypeError: movie.genres.some is not a function.
(in 'movie.genres.some(function(item){return item.name === genre;})',
'movie.genres.some' is undefined) `
```

```
Movie class =>  
  title: string,
  ...,
  genres: Genre[]

Genre class => 
  id: number,
  name: string
```

```js
FilterMovies = (genre: string) => {
  let fmovies: Movie[] = this.state.movies.filter((movie) => {
    let data = movie.genres.some((item) => item.name === genre);
    return data;
  });
```

Am I doing this stuff right or did i mess up one of the functions? Any help would be very much appreciated!

edit: here's an example of a movie object
[image]

Comment: Is there a chance for some items of `this.state.movies` to have ***missing*** `genres` property?

Comment: Can you show an example of your movies object?

Comment: Are you sure this is not a data issue on your part? Nothing seems wrong. It is more likely that your data is inconsistent and sometimes `genre` does not exist in `movies`

Comment: check whether movie.genres is an array or not before proceeding with some function

if(!Array.isArray(movie.genres)) return;
movie.genres.some((item) => item.name === genre);

Comment: Where is `this.state.movies` populated with data?

Comment: i populate this `this.state.movies` in componentDidMount()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as some comments suggested, i was able to solve the problem with the following:

- found out my object wasn't an array so i used `Object.values` to get the collections values
- i made sure to check if every movie has a genre object that is not null nor undefined

although it probably still isn't perfect yet it works as of now so here it is:

```
FilterMovies = (genre: string) => {

let fmovies: Movie[] = this.state.movies.filter((movie) => {
  let genreObj;
  movie.genres != null || typeof movie.genres !== "undefined"
    ? (genreObj = Object.values(movie.genres))
    : null;
  let genreNames: string[] = [];

  genreObj != null || typeof genreObj !== "undefined"
    ? genreObj?.forEach((genre) => {
        genreNames.push(genre.name);
      })
    : null;

  let data = genreNames.some((item) => item === genre);
  return data;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error message you're getting. The `genres` property of the `Movie` class is not really an array of `Genre` as all arrays have a `some` property (assuming you didn't remove it). Most likely `genres` property is just a single `Genre` object (a typo).

Comment: why should the movie not have more than one genre? he is pluggin in the search genre and wants to check if in the genres array in each movie object this search genre exists

Comment: I'm not suggesting a movie should have just one genre. I'm saying he probably did that, mistakenly, for him to have gotten this kind of error. That's the best explanation for what's going on, without seeing the actual definition of the `Movie` class

Comment: if you are guessing then maybe dont post your answe. A comment would be fine.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty good guess to me. The error indicates that `movie.genres` is definitely an object which isn't an array.